# refresh is not working for submenu path in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

- Hello everyone, I am using react router `"react-router-dom"` with  `<Switch>` and `<Route>`

.
 - In my website I have ***menus*** and ***submenus***. 
 - ex :: **menus**  (with path in bracket)

```
  1) Home ('/home') , 2) Profile ('/profile') , 3) Admin ('/admin')
```

- ex :: **submenu** :: only *Admin* tab has *submenu*
  `a) setting ('/admin/setting') and  b) History ('/admin/history')`
- **App.js**

  ```
   constructor(props) {
     history = createBrowserHistory();

     if (window.performance) {
       localStorage.setItem("currentpath",window.location.pathname);
       this.login();
      }
    }

    login = () =>{
       //ajax call
       //after ajax response 

          let  currentpath =  localStorage.getItem("currentpath");
          if(currentpath)
              this.history.push(currentpath );
          else
             this.history.push('/home');
    }




   render() {
     return (
        <React.Fragment>
           <Router history={this.history}>
            <div>
              <Switch>
                 <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Login/>} /> 
                <Route exact path="/home" render={() =><HomepageLayout/>} />
                <Route path="/admin" render={() => <AdminPageLayout/>} />
                <Route path="/profile" render={() => <ProfilePageLayout />} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
  }
  ```

---

- Now the problem is, In `local server` refresh is ***working fine*** for all path.
  But in `live server` refresh is ***working*** when current page is `Home` and `Profile`. But for `Admin->setting` or `Admin->history` ***submenu*** tab refresh is ***not working.***
- These errors i am getting in console

  ```
   GEThttp://www.websoft.com/admin/setting                   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 322ms]

   GEThttp://www.websoft.com/admin/static/css/1.3ac8ff05.chunk.css   [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 341ms]

   GEThttp://www.websoft.com/admin/static/js/1.ef821ff9.chunk.js     [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 324ms]

   GEThttp://www.websoft.com/admin/static/js/main.f0eaa457.chunk.js  [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 329ms]

   GEThttp://www.websoft.com/admin/static/css/main.83e337cf.chunk.css

   The stylesheet http://www.websoft.com/admin/static/css/1.3ac8ff05.chunk.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

   The script from “http://www.websoft.com/admin/static/js/1.ef821ff9.chunk.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type
  ```
- Its adding `admin` in path of chunk file when I refresh **submenu**.

Comment: i have added routes, its in same page app.js

Comment: I don't see any `Route` for `/admin/setting` and `/admin/history` where did you define those? Inside `Admin` component? If so, show that part of the code too.

Comment: That is written in adminLayoutComponent, in the same way as it is written in app.js for routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You haven't shared your `package.json` but parameter "**homepage**" in
  package.json is very useful for making *buildings*.
- I had same problem, I changed `"homepage": "."` in my `package.josn` to
  `"homepage": "/"`.
- If it doesn't work shared your current `package.json` for solving issue.